# Sequential ledger-like entries in NodeJS with Async/ Await

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, sequelize.js, sequential

I'm designing an accounting/ book-keeping application and my table has the following columns -

1. Transaction ID
2. Transaction Details
3. Amount
4. Closing Balance

All the transactions are fed to NodeJS function one-by-one through a queue

However, while saving each transaction, I have to fetch the previous transaction to get the last closing balance and add current transaction amount to the same to get the new closing balance

But I have to use async/await to fetch previous transaction so the event loop is free for a few milliseconds during which the function receives a new transaction event from the user. This is causing a lot of inconsistencies with the data as sometimes 2 rows with the same closing balance are inserted.

```
const prevTransaction = await Transaction.findOne({
    where: { userId },
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
})

await Transaction.create({
    userId,
    amount,
    closingBalance: prevTransaction ? prevTransaction.closingBalance + amount : amount,
    transactionDate
})
```

Now if the system receives a lot of events in bulk then there could be some inconsistencies in data due to the gap between GET & INSERT query.

In some scenarios, this is the data that's inserted

| ID | Amount | ClosingBalance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 20 | 40 |
| 3 | 20 | 40 |
| 4 | 10 | 50 |
| 5 | 20 | 60 |

When ideally it should be -

| ID | Amount | ClosingBalance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 20 | 40 |
| 3 | 20 | 60 |
| 4 | 10 | 70 |
| 5 | 20 | 90 |

Any particular way I could tweak the above code to get the sequential effect?

This is the reason I'm using a BullJS queue is so that transactions are processed one-by-one. But this issue still persists because of the 2 await calls.

Comment: Where did you store a queue?

Comment: @Anatoly I'm using BullJS for queues and it uses Redis for queue management

Comment: If you have an incoming queue from which you get transactions one by one how is it possible that another transaction will be processed in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarily solved this problem by pausing the job queue if any transaction is being processed and resuming it once the transaction is inserted - [link](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/903)

Would love to hear about any alternate approaches since this approach is relying on a third-party library.